# My rpi is not detecting my sense hat

Tags: pi-4, sense-hat

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1c -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- 46 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 5c -- -- 5f 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 6a -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Comment: You should not need sudo with i2cdetect.  What is your question?  How do you know the sense hat is not being detected.  Please edit this and any other additional information into your question.

Answer (score 3):

I think your HAT is working for an interface and hardware point of view.  The sensors are normally found at:

- 1C / 6A is the LSM9DS1 - Accelerometer and Magnetometer
- 46 is the Screen / Joystick
- 5C is the LPS25H Pressure / Temperature chip
- 5F is the HTS221 Humidity / Temperature chip

The latest version of the software for Python can be found on [GIHUB here](https://github.com/astro-pi/python-sense-hat) and the hardware diagram is [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/sense-hat/images/Sense-HAT-V1_0.pdf)