# Sense Hat with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sense-hat

I was wondering if it is possible to use the sense hat on ubuntu. I recently bought a pi 8gb and found out that raspian is only 32 bit thus would not allow me to use all 8gb of ram so I switched to a ubuntu build for the pi that is 64 bit but have found that the sense hat package isn't there. I've tried searching around and haven't found much. Any ideas?

Comment: Interested to see what you are running that needs 8Gb - this is not Windows :-). ZFS is the only thing that springs to mind that eats more the 4Gb around here...

Comment: Running a nexus server off it

Comment: Too many software stacks come up under a search for Nexus :-) So I'll trust you!!!  To me a server sits on its own rather than sensors but I'm often accused of being data centre orientated (i.e. one box one job).

Comment: Well I wanna run nexus but once it's going it doesn't take much memory so I figured I'd run some other stuff too

Answer (score 1):

Note as addition to the below, you can now download the packages from the emulators author documented [here](https://sense-emu.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1/index.html)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa://waveform/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-sense-emu python3-sense-emu sense-emu-tools
```

Please take care using any repository if you do not know the author!

Sorry this is a series of links but I do not know a simple answer for this device.

The sense hat is just a series of displays, switches and sensors nicely packaged on one board:

- 8 × 8 RGB LED matrix
- a five – button joystick
- Gyroscope
- Accelerometer
- Magnetometer
- Temperature
- Barometric pressure
- Humidity

with a Python library to wrap all the data behind an easy to use interface.  The ports used by this hat can be seen [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/117161/my-rpi-is-not-detecting-my-sense-hat) in my old answer.

The first thing I would try is the Ubuntu equivalent of `sudo apt install sense-hat` to see if that gets you the Python library.

If that library is not available then details on installing it can be found on GitHub issue #79 [here](https://github.com/astro-pi/python-sense-hat/issues/79)

It is important to follow that thread carefully ESPECIALLY the blacklist details on [this thread](https://github.com/J-Pai/EnvTrackerNode).

I would actually recommend the 64-Bit version of Raspberry Pi OS or stick with the hybrid 64-bit kernel / 32-user space a little longer as these are better supported by the RPT/RPF software than other operating systems.

Comment: Did not realize there was a 64 bit one I used the imager and it only has 32 bit

Comment: It's gone off the new 'simple' (read dumbed down) website but the main place to track it is https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=275372&hilit=64+bit.  Given Ubuntu has come in as a runner  it does not surprise me it gets buried with six months beta :-)