# Sensehat apt package on Manjaro ARM? Insights?

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, ubuntu, 64-bit, sense-hat

First post on here.

I have a Raspberry pi 4b+ 8GB that I am super happy with. I've been messing around with different operating systems on this device and I find that the Manjaro ARM distro is really nice!

So I am not a highly knowledgeable linux user however I am very enthusiastic. I've looked into getting a sense hat to work on a non-raspbian OS with little success. Ive followed a few guides and am aware that there are packages available on other distros.

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/sense-hat-to-work-on-pi-3-b-running-ubuntu-mate-18-04-3-lts/20878/3

https://github.com/astro-pi/python-sense-hat/issues/79

[Sense Hat with Ubuntu](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118854/sense-hat-with-ubuntu)

I do know that the sensehat software is not readily available via the pacman package manager.

My guess why it is suggested to stick with the raspberry pi OS is because it is loading firmware (libraries?) on to the board that other ARM based OS's may not load with.

I think I could probably figure out how to do this if someone could even describe in a way I could understand what is happening between the OS and the sensehat board and perhaps what programs or config files are associated with this communication.

I've seen it suggested to download the python sensehat-emu package on python however wouldn't this just load the emulator and not the libraries to interact with the actual board?

If you have a better understanding and some spare time I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction. I am fairly good at debugging so if I understood what was going on I can probably figure it out.

Cheers